# React Native with Redux- Problems updating state correctly

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I'm trying to upload images that I've base64 encoded but it doesn't seem to save the state to the app so I can upload the images to my server.  The state only seems to save within the function and not to the entire component.  Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong?

```
  _selectImage(uri) {
    NativeModules.ReadImageData.readImage(uri, (image) => {
        this.state = {
            selected: image
        };

        console.log(this.state)
    });
}


render() {
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
   <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', }}>
      <TouchableOpacity style={ styles.button } onPress={ this._addImage.bind( this ) }>
        <Text>Add Image</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity style={ styles.button } onPress={this._uploadImage} >
        <Text>Upload Image</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>

    <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.imageGrid}>
        { this.state.images.map((image) => {
          return (
            <TouchableHighlight onPress={this._selectImage.bind(null, image.uri)}>
              <Image key={ _generateUUID() } style={styles.image} source={{ uri: image.uri }} />
            </TouchableHighlight>
          );
        })
      }
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  </View>
);
```

}
};

Comment: You probably need to use `this.setState({})` vs `this.state = {}`

Comment: When I use setstate I get the error that says setstate is not a function.

Comment: Try `onPress={this._selectImage.bind(this, image.uri)}` along with `this.setState({ selected: image })`

Comment: It's not throwing the setstate is not a function error anymore but it's also not updating the state of the component.  Thank you btw for all your help @NaderDabit

Comment: Hey no problem. Are you sure it's not updating the state? If you're inspecting the state with `console.log(this.state)` to test this you may want to use `setImmediate(() => console.log(this.state))` because the state change will not be available until the next process tick.

Answer (score 0):

First, ***this-bind*** your _selectImage-method in constructor. Then use "setState" instead of this.state = {...}

You need only once to create the state object, best in constructor. Use then setState instead for further modifications.

```
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {selected: null};
      this._selectImage = this._selectImage.bind(this);
  }

  _selectImage(uri) {
    NativeModules.ReadImageData.readImage(uri, (image) => {
        this.setState({
            selected: image
        });

        console.log(this.state)
    });
}
```